# GridView HyperLink field in C#

Tags: c#, gridview, hyperlink

Take a look at the following code:

```
<asp:HyperLinkField 
    DataNavigateUrlFields="NameID" 
    DataNavigateUrlFormatString="names.aspx?nameid={0}"
    DataTextField="name" 
    HeaderText="Name" 
    ItemStyle-Width="100px"
    ItemStyle-Wrap="true" />
```

It takes only the name id to navigate to the next page. How will I include the two other parameters which are not in the gridview. The navigate URL I'm using has to take the keyword which is already present in the gridview and the other two parameters from the database table. I tried using all these codes. Nothing did work for me.

```
<asp:HyperLinkField DataTextField="Keyword" DataNavigateUrlFields="Keyword"
    DataNavigateUrlFormatString="KeywordSrchSumDtl.aspx?Keyword={0}&State={1}&City={2}"
    HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Bottom" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" />
```

I cant use the above the code because the state and city are not in the GridView but available in my data table.

I tried using the following code too, but it doesn't work:

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Keyword"  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="link" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<% # "KeywordSrchSumDtl.aspx?Keyword="Eval("Keyword")+"&State="+Request.QueryString["State"]%>' Text='<%# Eval("Keyword") %>'>
        </asp:HyperLink>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I also tried this:

```
        <asp:HyperLink ID="Link1" runat="Server" NavigateUrl='<%#redirectURL()+Server.UrlEncode((Eval("Keyword")).ToString())%>' Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Keyword") %>'>
        </asp:HyperLink>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

.aspx.cs

```c#
return "KeywordSrchSumDtl.aspx?Keyword=" + 
    //I DONNO HOW TO CALL THE KEYWORD HERE//
    + "&State=" + System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["State"]
    + "&City=" + System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["City"];
```

I don't know how to solve this.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use the `DataNavigateUrlFields` property, comma-delimited value with the fields for parameters in `"KeywordSrchSumDtl.aspx?Keyword={0}&State={1}&City={2}"`

```
<asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="Keyword,State,City"
                    DataNavigateUrlFormatString="KeywordSrchSumDtl.aspx?Keyword={0}&State={1}&City={2}" 
                    Text="View Details" />
```

A couple of examples:

[Passing two arguments in DataNavigateUrlFormatString in hyperlink field of .NET 2.0 Grid-View](http://techturf.wordpress.com/2007/10/15/passing-two-arguments-in-datanavigateurlformatstring-in-hyperlink-field-of-net-20-grid-view/)

[Pass Multiple Values from a GridView to Another Page  using ASP.NET](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=147)

**EDIT:**

Set `NavigateUrl` of HyperLink in `RowDataBound` event of `GridView`

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
              DataKeyNames="Keyword"
              DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
              onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Keyword"  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"          FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
      <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:HyperLink ID="link" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Keyword") %>' />
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    .......
</asp:GridView>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) 
{ 
 if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) 
 { 
    HyperLink hl = (HyperLink)e.Row.FindControl("link"); 
    if (hl != null) 
    { 
        DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem; 
        string keyword = drv["Keyword"].ToString(); 
        string state = Request.QueryString["State"]; 
        string city = Request.QueryString["City"]; 
        hl.NavigateUrl = "~/KeywordSrchSumDtl.aspx?Keyword=" + keyword + "&State=" + Server.UrlEncode(state) + "&City=" + Server.UrlEncode(city); 
    } 
 } 
}
```

Comment: A field or property with the name 'State' was not found on the selected data source. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: A field or property with the name 'State' was not found on the selected data source.

Source Error: 


Line 40:             dv = bindGridView();
Line 41:             GridView1.DataSource = dv;
Line 42:             GridView1.DataBind();
Line 43: 
Line 44:         }

Comment: STATE and CITY is not present in the gridview.

Comment: but it wont work if those fields are not present in the table ryt??

Comment: Only the Keyword, if you look at the code behind you will see the values of the other parameters are actually coming from the Request object.

Comment: I donno its not taking the other two parameters.                         This is how it redirects -->                                     http://reliable/folder2/KeywordSrchSumDtl.aspx?Keyword=ups                                                                   &State=&City=

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `string.Format` method

```
NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("KeywordSrchSumDtl.aspx?Keyword={0}&State={1}&City={2}", DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Keyword"), Request.QueryString["State"], Request.QueryString["City"]) %>'
```

Comment: Your code doesnt bind the keyword column to the table. So i added                         <asp:Label ID="lblKey" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Keyword") %>'></asp:Label>        now it binds. but no output shown.. thanks

Comment: Yes...!! I got the output.. Thanks.. :)

Answer (score -1):

Finally it Navigates by the following code,

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) 
{ 
 if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) 
 { 
      HyperLink hl = (HyperLink)e.Row.FindControl("Link");
      if (hl != null)
      {
           DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
           string keyword = drv["Keyword"].ToString().Trim();
           string state = strState.ToString().Trim();
           string city = strCity.ToString().Trim();                 
           hl.NavigateUrl = "KeywordSrchSumDtl.aspx?Keyword=" + keyword + "&Geo=" + geo                             + "&Site=" + site;
       }
       }
      }
```

Thank u guys for the help.

Answer (score -1):

```
Some time we need to pass multiple parameters with hyperlink in Gridview, datagrid or any data list control then we can use following code:-</br> 

**CODE:-** 
<asp:GridView ID="gvFin" runat="server" CellPadding="1" AutoGenerateColumns="false"> 

<Columns>
     <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="4%" HeaderStyle-Width="4%" SortExpression="CDL"
    HeaderText="CDL#" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
   <asp:HyperLink ID="lnk1" runat="server" 
   Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"TestValue") %>'
   NavigateUrl='<%# "javascript:ShowACP(\"" + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ID")     + "\",\"" + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ACCOUNTPLAN") + "\");" %>'                                                  ForeColor="Blue" /  </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>


**JavaScript Function**

function ShowACP(id, acplabel) 
{            if (acplabel == "No")
{
                window.location = "#";
            }
            else</br> 
                window.location = "Default.aspx?gid=" + id;
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

You may initialize DataNavigateUrlFields from Code Behind with string[]:

```
yourHyperLinkField.DataNavigateUrlFields = new string[] { "Keyword", "State", "City" };
```