# Gridview Hyperlink Not Working

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to insert a hyperlink field thru the wizard. But when I run the application i get the text with BLUE link but its not clickable.

This is my CODE:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="stepID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="stepID,stepName,stepStartdate,stepEndDate,stageID" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/Supervisor/editSteps.aspx?stepID={0}&amp;stepName={1}&amp;Sdate={2}&amp;EDate={3}&amp;stgD={4}" DataTextField="stepName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="stageID" HeaderText="stageID" SortExpression="stageID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="stepStartdate" HeaderText="stepStartdate" SortExpression="stepStartdate" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="stepEndDate" HeaderText="stepEndDate" SortExpression="stepEndDate" />
    </Columns>
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [tblsteps] WHERE ([stageID] = @stageID)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="stageID" QueryStringField="StgID" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

No errors or warning when i run this application.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GridView HyperLink field in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12823422/gridview-hyperlink-field-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine,I've tested it on my side and the hyperlink is working.I suspect that the hyperlink is being disabled through javascript or CSS.

You can confirm this by temporarily removing all CSS and javascript references from the page in question.

If it's CSS that's disabling the hyperlink you can inspect the style of the hyperlink when you run your web page in the browser by following these steps:

1. Run your web page in Gooogle Chrome
2. Press `Ctrl+Shift+I` to bring up the HTML inspection console
3. Locate the hyper link in the HTML (the `<a>` element)
4. Inspect the style rule which is disabling the element and remove it from your CSS file:

[image: Inspecting HTML in Google Chrome]

Answer (score 0):

Add a virtual document folder on IIS where you have your webpage and on your page.aspx code:
`DataNavigateUrlFormatString="http://webserver/{0}" DataNavigateUrlFields="FieldName"`

and thats it. sale bato.